# How do I delete an object from an Entity Framework model without first loading it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am quite sure I've seen the answer to this question somewhere, but as I couldn't find it with a couple of searches on SO or google, I ask it again anyway...

In Entity Framework, the only way to delete a data object seems to be

```
MyEntityModel ent = new MyEntityModel();
ent.DeleteObject(theObjectToDelete);
ent.SaveChanges();
```

However, this approach requires the object to be loaded to, in this case, the Controller first, just to delete it. Is there a way to delete a business object referencing only for instance its ID?

If there is a smarter way using Linq or Lambda expressions, that is fine too. The main objective, though, is to avoid loading data just to delete it.

Comment: there is a way to do this nice and generically: http://j.mp/f0x0Bh

Comment: @BritishDeveloper: Interesting! However, I have after this question was asked realized that there are often good cause of retrieving the entity first, at least if there are foreign key relations involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an object by id with entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471433/how-to-delete-an-object-by-id-with-entity-framework)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: Yeah, except this question was asked a year earlier...

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. The date is not essential. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha If you agree that it requires clarification please vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/add-clarification-link-to-possible-duplicate-automated-comment

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is worth knowing that the Entity Framework supports both to Linq to Entities and Entity SQL. If you find yourself wanting to do deletes or updates that could potentially affect many records you can use the equivalent of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

In Entity SQL this might look like

```
   Using db As New HelloEfEntities

        Dim qStr = "Delete " & _
                  "FROM Employee"
        db.ExecuteStoreCommand(qStr)
        db.SaveChanges()
    End Using
```

In this example, `db` is my `ObjectContext`. Also note that the `ExecuteStoreCommand` function takes an optional array of parameters.

Comment: This answer goes directly to the point of what the asker would like to do and should be marked as the accepted answer. Other solutions like constructing entity from nothing are less optimal. Also check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx

Comment: Why are you calling SaveChanges after the ExecuteStoreCommand?

Comment: This is not a good answer. It opens your code to possible SQL injections. And you don't have one of the top 2 advantages of EF : syntax check on compilation time.

Answer (score 8):

I found [this post](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Working_with_Ids_in_the_Entity_Framework.aspx), which states that there really is no better way to delete records. The explanation given was that all the foreign keys, relations etc that are unique for this record are also deleted, and so EF needs to have the correct information about the record. I am puzzled by why this couldn't be achieved without loading data back and forth, but as it's not going to happen very often I have decided (for now) that I won't bother.

If you do have a solution to this problem, feel free to let me know =)

Comment: How about using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 4):

Apologies in advance, but I have to question your goal.

If you delete an object without ever reading it, then you can't know if another user has changed the object in between the time you confirmed that you wanted to delete the object and the actual delete. In "plain old SQL", this would be like doing:

```
DELETE FROM FOO
WHERE ID = 1234
```

Of course, most people don't actually do this. Instead, they do something like:

```
DELETE FROM FOO
WHERE ID = 1234
  AND NAME = ?ExpectedName AND...
```

The point is that the delete should fail (do nothing) if another user has changed the record in the interim.

With this, better statement of the problem, there are two possible solutions when using the Entity Framework.

1. In your Delete method, the existing instance, compare the expected values of the properties, and delete if they are the same. In this case, the Entity Framework will take care of writing a DELETE statement which includes the property values.
2. Write a stored procedure which accepts both the IDE and the other property values, and execute that.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid goal if your objects are never modified during their lifespan and/or your query to FIND the objects to delete implies all the properties you would be verifying are already at the correct value anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There's a way to spoof load an entity by re-calculating it's EntityKey. It looks like a bit of a hack, but might be the only way to do this in EF.

Blog article on [Deleting without Fetching](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/Entity-Framework-Beta3-Deleting-without-fetching.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can create an object with the same id and pass it through to the delete
BUT its good for simple objects if you have complex relations you may need more than that

```
                var user = new User { ID = 15 };
                context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var toDelete = new MyEntityModel{
    GUID = guid,
    //or ID = id, depending on the key
    };
Db.MyEntityModels.Attach(toDelete);
Db.MyEntityModels.DeleteObject(toDelete);
Db.SaveChanges();
```

In case your key contains multiple columns, you need to provide all values (e.g. GUID, columnX, columnY etc).

Have also a look [here](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/delete-by-id-entity-framework-how-to.html) for a generic function if you feel for something fancy.

Comment: This is the best way (I call it using a placeholder object) but it does suffer from the same concurrency concerns brought up by Stuntz below.

Answer (score 2):

With Entity Framework 5 there is [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). Available on NuGet. Then you can write something like:

```
context.Users.Delete(u => u.Id == id);
```

It is also useful for bulk deletes.

Comment: This is an incredible library! Thanks