# How to delete an object by id with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity

It seems to me that I have to retrieve an object before I delete it with entity framework like below

```
var customer = context.Customers.First(c => c.Id == 1);

context.DeleteObject(customer);

context.Savechanges();
```

So I need to hit database twice. Is there a easier way?

Answer (score 154):

In Entity Framework 6 the delete action is `Remove`. Here is an example

```
Customer customer = new Customer () { Id = id };
context.Customers.Attach(customer);
context.Customers.Remove(customer);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Why `Attach`? Why not just `Remove` and `SaveChanges`?

Comment: You have to attach your entity in the context because if you don't do that, you will receive an error while removing.
EF can remove entities in this context only

Comment: @runeks according to the manual the entity must exist in the context before the Remove operation can be performed. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.remove?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: i didn't use attach, and it woks fine

Comment: People might confuse the usage of Remove between Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework. It is true that for Entity Framework, the `Remove` method needs to be called after the `Attach` method, as mentioned by @Pierre-Luc.


However, for [EFCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.remove), the `Remove` method will begin tracking the entity as deleted.

Comment: I don't think `Attach()` is necessary unless you're doing more with the object. From what I can see, that method is used the track it in the database during execution.

Answer (score 63):

The same as @Nix with a small change to be strongly typed:

If you don't want to query for it just create an entity, and then delete it.

```cs
Customer customer = new Customer () { Id = id };
context.Customers.Attach(customer);
context.Customers.DeleteObject(customer);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Not perfect as it throws an exception if the object is missing: "DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."  I'd like it to ignore this, like a DELETE statement would.

Comment: sorry, this causes validation which is not needed and expected always!

Answer (score 39):

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/502795/746754).

With Entity Framework there is [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus) (extensions library).
Available on NuGet. Then you can write something like:

```
// DELETE all users which has been inactive for 2 years
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.LastLoginDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2))
     .Delete();
```

It is also useful for bulk deletes.

Comment: It defies reason that this isn't part of the core EF library by now.

Comment: @FerretallicA - agreed.

Comment: this method is obsolete use: 
    context.Users.Where(user=> user.Id == id).Delete();

Comment: It doesn't work with Azure SQL DataWarehouse due to error "A FROM clause is currently not supported in a DELETE statement.". But the raw SQL as in Jonik's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091589) works.

Comment: Is context.SaveChanges() needed?

Comment: @TomasKubes SaveChanges() is not needed since the EF Plus's .Delete() call automatically does it.

Answer (score 25):

Since Entity Framework Core 7 you can use this:

```cs
await context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == 1).ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

Comment: However, be aware that the `ExecuteDeleteAsync()` doesn't respect the Change Tracker and transactional `SaveChanges()`. Thus, you have to create a facade transaction manually and handle the commit/rollback.

Answer (score 23):

If you dont want to query for it just create an entity, and then delete it.

```
Customer customer  = new Customer() {  Id = 1   } ; 
context.AttachTo("Customers", customer);
context.DeleteObject(customer);
context.Savechanges();
```

Answer (score 12):

I am using the following code in one of my projects:

```
    using (var _context = new DBContext(new DbContextOptions<DBContext>()))
    {
        try
        {
            _context.MyItems.Remove(new MyItem() { MyItemId = id });
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!_context.MyItems.Any(i => i.MyItemId == id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

This way, it will query the database twice only if an exception occurs when trying to remove the item with the specified ID. Then if the item is not found, it returns a meaningful message; otherwise, it just throws the exception back (you can handle this in a way more fit to your case using different catch blocks for different exception types, add more custom checks using if blocks etc.).

[I am using this code in a MVC .Net Core/.Net Core project with Entity Framework Core.]

Comment: This is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 9):

In EF Core, if you don't care if the object exists or not, and you just care that it will not be in the DB, the simplest would be:

```
context.Remove(new Customer(Id: id));  // adds the object in "Deleted" state
context.SaveChanges();                 // commits the removal
```

You don't really need `Attach()` - it adds the object to the change tracker in the `Unchanged` state and `Remove()` adds the object to the tracker in the `Deleted` state. The most important thing, however, is that you do only one roundtrip to the backend.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is actually taken from Scott Allen's course titled ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals. I thought I'd share because I think it is slightly simpler and more intuitive than any of the answers here already. Also note according to Scott Allen and other trainings I've done, find method is an optimized way to retrieve a resource from database that can use caching if it already has been retrieved. In this code, collection refers to a DBSet of objects. Object can be any generic object type.

```
        var object = context.collection.Find(id);  
        context.collection.Remove(object);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: object could be null. If it null, .Remove(object); will throw an exception.

Comment: While this is the easiest syntactically, the OP specifically asked for a way to delete without hitting the database twice.  This works but it performs a SELECT (Find) and then a DELETE (Remove/SaveChanges) on the database...and as @demonicdaron already mentioned, it fails if the Find returns a null.

Comment: Yes, this answer complete misses the point.

Answer (score 2):

dwkd's answer mostly worked for me in Entity Framework core, except when I saw this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Customer' cannot
>   be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'}
>   is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure
>   that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
>   Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to
>   see the conflicting key values.

To avoid the exception, I updated the code:

```
Customer customer = context.Customers.Local.First(c => c.Id == id);
if (customer == null) {
    customer = new Customer () { Id = id };
    context.Customers.Attach(customer);
}
context.Customers.Remove(customer);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I believe you want to use `FirstOrDefault`?

Answer (score 2):

A smaller version (when compared to previous ones):

```
var customer = context.Find(id);
context.Delete(customer);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Please provide some context to this code snippet, and perhaps some explanation of what it does better than the other answers left in the past decade.

Comment: No. The very point of the question is how to prevent this roundtrip.

Answer (score 2):

From official documentation (and the most efficient one I have found so far):

```
Student studentToDelete = new Student() { ID = id };
_context.Entry(studentToDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: You need to link that "official document" that mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

Raw sql query is fastest way I suppose

```
public void DeleteCustomer(int id)
{
   using (var context = new Context())
   {
      const string query = "DELETE FROM [dbo].[Customers] WHERE [id]={0}";
      var rows = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query,id);
      // rows >= 1 - count of deleted rows,
      // rows = 0 - nothing to delete.
   }
}
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using strongly typed object funtionality in EF.

Comment: This compromises EF identity cash. After this EF will still return to you your deleted entity.

Comment: It works with Azure SQL DataWarehouse, when other solutions do not.

Comment: If you're doing this, you might as well not use an ORM. I imagine that this would compromise the EF cache.

Comment: This style is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. In this specific example you're protected because the variable is an integer, but never use this pattern with a string variable.

Comment: great answer for when your Id property is private

Comment: @thelem There is no SQL injection attack possible here.  `id` is an int, so there is no way to change to be `1 OR 1=1;` like there would be with a string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Easier and more understandable version.

```
var customer = context.Find<Customer>(id);
context.Remove(customer);
context.SaveChanges();
```