# Web API DELETE verb

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass an entire object to a delete method of my API and the execution never gets to it.

Client (angular)

```
$http({
                      method: 'DELETE',
                      url: framewidth + "codebook/DeleteSection/",
                      data: $scope.codesection
                  })
```

Server (Web API 2)

```
[HttpDelete]
    public int DeleteSection(Domain.Code.CodeSection section)
    {
     //   repo.Delete(Mapper.Map<EF.Code.CodeSection>(section));

        return (section.Id);
    }
```

The EXACT same set up but with POST works for the method that does the Create operation.
Is it nor possible to pass entire object with a DELETE verb request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you passing whole object when deleting? pass only id. [read related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

```
public int DeleteSection(int id)
{
   var c = new Domain.Code.CodeSection(){ Id = id};
   db.Entry(c).State= EntityState.Deleted;
   db.SaveChanges();
   return id;
}
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948911/entity-framework-4-1-how-do-i-delete-by-object-id)

Comment: That's what I had originally . However I am using entity framework at the backend, so in order to delete an entity i first have to have an entity to delete. If I only pass the id I will have to have EF first run a SELECT just to find the entity to delete. That doesn't seem like the most efficient way.

Comment: Ooo that's nice, I'll use that. That's what I was originally thinking but wasn't sure how to accomplish in the EF world. Thanks!